# React useRef hook - How to programmatically trigger a click event for multiple <td>'s?

Tags: reactjs

I have a `<tr>` that contains multiple `<td>`'s. Each `<td>` has a click event but I would like to programmatically click through React useRef hook or any other hook that can achieve my goal.

Since all `<td>`'s share the same className, I can trigger the click event through the DOM as per below:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('cell')[cellNumber].click()

// Example: to trigger the click of first cell:
// document.getElementsByClassName('cell')[0].click()
```

**Sample Code** - I tried assigning a shared ref `cellRef`
:

```
export const Row = ({ props }) => {
  const cellRef = useRef(null)

  return (
    <tr>
      {row.map((c, i) => (
        <td
          className="cell"
          ref={cellRef}
          onClick={handleCell}
        >
        </td>
        ))}
    </tr>
  )
}
```

Below only triggers the last `<td>`, I want to choose the cell number:

```
cellRef.current.click()
```

Comment: Does the cell have to actually be clicked or can you just call handleCell many times?

Comment: @windowsill The goal is to have it clicked by mouse which already works, and also programmatically from other sources. Obviously using the DOM does the job, but wondering if there is a recommended ReactJS approach.

Comment: What I mean is calling your handler for each cell because you already have the reference for the handleCell function, instead of trying to make a bunch of refs you don't need: `for each row: for each col: handleCell(row, col)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use hooks inside any loops. Here is what you can do in React.

For your Refs, you could assign an empty array to your `Ref` like this.

```
const cellRef = useRef([]);
```

In this way, you can access each of your `<td>`s with `cellRef.current[n]`, where `n` is your `index` that you passed in as a `key` from your `map()` function to your `<td>`.

In plain English, you are basically labeling each of your `<td>` and assign them a number, which is the `index`. This helps React recognize what has changed and what has not.

In your `<td>`, you could write

```
      {row.map((c, index) => (
        <td
          className="cell"
          key={index}
          ref={(ele)=> cellRef.current[index] = ele}
          onClick={()=> handleCell(index)}
        >
        </td>
        ))}
```

To trigger any events to the`<td>` you desired, you simply choose by their `index`.
Make sure you pass in `index` as a parameter of `handleCell`.

Comment: That's pretty clever, I'm filing that away for future use